# Magento2 cant login to admin - redirect issue

Tags: redirect, authentication, backend, magento2

i have installed Magento2 on server. Frontend is ok, when i go to backend i see login form, but when i enter my login details, nothing happens, login form is loaded again in Chrome.  In firefox i get error too many redirects.
url of admin looks like

http://........../admin/admin/index/index/key/b734e85ebfafe5784ea6d71d8f584cc6dc52d908d49bb574880afcc945650593/

some hints where should i look to solve this ?

thanks

Comment: Can you please update your .htaccess file ?

Comment: found this in nginx access log>

Comment: [09/Nov/2016:21:17:10 +0000] "GET /admin/admin/index/index/key/cf3e02c3f6f007c58b2c5644df385633d9421c2c892662893337757a1b27d7c1/ HTTP/1.1 "302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWe$   and still repeating with different key

Comment: how should update my .htacess file ?  thanks

Comment: I mean update your question with `.htaccess` code, nginx log is normal no problem in that.

Comment: uploaded it here, as is too long  http://textuploader.com/d5ult

Comment: No issue in this please check `local.xml` is your session store in file or database ?